# can we scroll text in a <input type="text" in html using css or jquery

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css

please help me to scroll text in a html input text field  using css or jquery on android device.
  I already tried with overflow: auto; and using iscroll.

Comment: Use `textarea` instead of `text`?

Answer (score 6):

If you want scrolling textboxes than you are doing it in a wrong way, if you want scroll, use `textarea` instead of `input type=text`, even if it's possible, don't do it, it's just wrong approach.

As far as the area is concerned, if you want to have `input type text` looks for your `textarea` you can use

```
textarea {
    height: 30px;
    resize: none;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/627Ex/)

Comment: yes i know it's an wrong approach but how can i scroll input type=text

Comment: @Amnishyadav I said, if you don't have sufficient space, go for `textarea`, that's what textarea is for, input type text is to fetch base details like name, sex etc, not for address...

Comment: k but i am using virtual keyboard and it open input type:text, field so i don't have any other option like text area..

Comment: @Amnishyadav modify the source